# KestrelServerLimits.KeepAliveTimeout

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

With the following WebHost setup (notice KeepAliveTimeout):

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel(x => x.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .Build();
```

we expect to have kestrel kill the request (given execution lasts more than 1 second) and see an error code returned. However, it seems to do nothing.

What are we missing?

Comment: ASP.NET core 2?

Comment: @CodyG. yup! `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />`

Comment: KeepAliveTimeout is only for idle connections between requests, not during requests. There is no built in request timeout.

Comment: @Tratcher - thanks! Is there any plan to add request timeout?

Comment: No. The old one relied on thread abort which doesn't work in the async world. You can add a basic one by chaining the RequestAborted cancellation token and adding a timeout there. Then you need your request handling logic to register with the token.